# How can I correctly match an Option<usize> enum variant in Rust and return its value?

Tags: rust

I need to return the `Option<usize>` in case the the mode is _B.

```
pub struct Request {
   _mode: Mode,
}

pub enum Mode {
    A,
    // _B stores the len
    _B(Option<usize>)
}

impl Request {
    fn get_len(&self) -> Option<usize> {
        let len = match &self._mode {
            A => Some(0),
            // Here I need to the value stored in _B
            _B => _B
        };
        len
    }
}
```

I got an error

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> main.rs:23:19
   |
20 |           let len = match &self._mode {
   |  ___________________-
21 | |             A => Some(0),
   | |                  ------- this is found to be of type `Option<{integer}>`
22 | |             // Here I need to the value stored in _B
23 | |             _B => _B
   | |                   ^^ expected enum `Option`, found `&Mode`
24 | |         };
   | |_________- `match` arms have incompatible types
   |
   = note:   expected enum `Option<{integer}>`
           found reference `&Mode`
```

What is the right way to write this part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - new answer:

```
impl Request {
    fn get_len(&self) -> Option<usize> {
        let len = match self._mode {
            Mode::_B(val) => val,
            _ => Some(0)
        };
        len
    }
}
```

In the `match`, refer to `self` directly, don't add another `&` to it, and in the match arms, 1) use `_` for anything that isn't what you want, since you are throwing away anything other than what you want, and 2) reference `_B_` via its type and get its value.

Again, I've not being using Rust long, but I am pretty sure you might be able to write this as

```
impl Request {
    fn get_len(&self) -> Option<usize> {
        match self._mode {
            Mode::_B(val) => val,
            _ => Some(0)
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, make the match itself an expression, not a statement: The function returns the value of that expression.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I've not been using Rust very long, but shouldn't it be more like

```
let len = match &self._mode {
   Some(_B) => _B,
   _ => 0
};
```

assuming I am interpreting what you are trying to do with `Some(0)` correctly.

Comment: I need to return Option<usize>. So your approach also returns the error:
```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> main.rs:23:13
   |
20 |         let len = match &self._mode {
   |                         ----------- this expression has type `&Mode`
...
23 |             Some(_B) => _B
   |             ^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Mode`, found enum `Option`
   |
   = note: expected enum `Mode`
              found enum `Option<_>`
```

Comment: Right! You’ve declared self as a ref, so why are you further referencing it in the match? What if you had your original code with match self._mode?

Comment: I've edited my reply and it compiles, it may be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
pub struct Request {
    mode: Mode,
}

pub enum Mode {
    A,
    B(Option<usize>),
}

impl Request {
    fn get_len(&self) -> Option<usize> {
        let len = match &self.mode {
            Mode::A => Some(0),
            Mode::B(len) => *len,
        };

        len
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r1 = Request{
        mode: Mode::B(Some(5))
    };
    
    println!("{:?}", r1.get_len());
    
     let r2 = Request{
        mode: Mode::A
    };
    
    println!("{:?}", r2.get_len());
}
```

Here is playground link [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c729e2422201a01121be418bb6d04430)